# Print/export csv file into array

Tags: text-processing, perl, csv

I have the following data in a very large csv:

```
"sortorder","name","description"
"1","B.1","Boiler room"
"2","1.1","First office"
"3","1.2","Second office"
etc...
```

Which I would like to end up in something like this:

```
{ name => 'B.1', description => 'Boiler room', sortorder => 1 },
{ name => '1.1', description => 'First office', sortorder => 2 },
{ name => '1.2', description => 'Second office', sortorder => 3 },
etc.
```

How can I accomplish this in something with perl or bash?

Answer (score 1):

General **sed** solution (without fields resorting)

```
sed '
    1{
        h
        d
    }
    G
    :a
    s/\(^\|,\)\([^=]\+\n\)"\?\([^,]\+\)"\?,\?/\1 \3 => \2/
    ta
    s/^/{/
    s/\n/ },/
    ' file.csv
```

But if you'd like a fist field become the last - just add

```
s/\([^,]*\), \([^\n]*\)/\2, \1/
```

after `ta`

Answer (score 1):

A little ruby one-liner

```
  ruby -rcsv -ne '
    row = CSV.parse_line($_)
    if $. == 1 then
      keys = row
    else
      h = Hash[keys.zip(row)]
      puts h.to_s + ","
    end
  '
```

outputs

```
{"sortorder"=>"1", "name"=>"B.1", "description"=>"Boiler room"},
{"sortorder"=>"2", "name"=>"1.1", "description"=>"First office"},
{"sortorder"=>"3", "name"=>"1.2", "description"=>"Second office"},
```

or Perl, that generates the complete data structure (array of hashes)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use Text::CSV;
use autodie;
use Data::Dump      qw/ dump /;

my @rows;
open my $fh, "<", shift @ARGV;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new( {binary => 1} );
my $keys = $csv->getline($fh);
while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {
    my %h;
    @h{ @$keys } = @$row;
    push @rows, \%h;
}

# print it
say dump \@rows;
```

outputs

```
[
  { description => "Boiler room", name => "B.1", sortorder => 1 },
  { description => "First office", name => 1.1, sortorder => 2 },
  { description => "Second office", name => 1.2, sortorder => 3 },
]
```

Comment: +1 for using Text::CSV - .csv files can have all sorts of little quirks and corner cases that make writing your own a pain.  also the required output looked suspiciously like a perl array of hashes anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open INFILE, "<", "inputfile";
open OUTFILE, ">", "outputfile";

$header_line = <INFILE>;
chop($header_line);
@headers = split /,/, $header_line;
foreach $header_column (@headers) {
    $header_column =~ s/^"(.*)"$/$1/;
}

while(<INFILE>) {
    chop($_); # clear the newline at the end of string
    @fields = split /,/; # split string by ,
    foreach $field (@fields) {
        $field =~ s/^"(.*)"$/$1/;
    }   
    for($i = 0; $i <= $#headers; $i++) {
        $fields[$i] = $headers[$i] . " => " . $fields[$i];
    }
    print OUTFILE "{ " . join(', ', @fields) . "},\n";
```

}

And with your `inputfile`

```
"sortorder","name","description"
"1","B.1","Boiler room"
"2","1.1","First office"
"3","1.2","Second office"
```

produces the output

```
{ name => 'name', description => 'description', sortorder => 'sortorder' },
{ name => 'B.1', description => 'Boiler room', sortorder => '1' },
{ name => '1.1', description => 'First office', sortorder => '2' },
{ name => '1.2', description => 'Second office', sortorder => '3' },
```

The script keeps the order of the columns from the first line.

Comment: Beware; this will break if any field has a `,` in it (eg in the description) and will produce wrong results if any field has a `"` in it (the `"` will get dropped).  It also assumes the fields are in a fixed order and never vary.

Comment: Thanks @StephenHarris for notes, commented previous version of the script.